# Incompatible block pointer types initializing 'CGFloat (^__strong)(CGFloat)' with an expression of type 'double (^)(CGFloat)'

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, cgfloat

I'm trying to create a block variable that takes a CGFloat argument and returns a CGFloat.

```
CGFloat (^debt)(CGFloat) = ^(CGFloat myFloat) {
   return myFloat * 444563.4004;
};
```

What is wrong with this definition? Why am I getting this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On iOS (and other 32-bit platforms), `CGFloat` is an alias for `float`.

Your literal (`444563.4004`) is a `double`, which promotes `myFloat` to a `double` and makes the return type of your block `double` (and not the `float` you said it would be when you declared `debt`). Either change the literal to a `float` (append `f` to the end of it), or cast it to `CGFloat`.

Comment: Great answer. Also, amazing ascii art!

Answer (score 5):

Another possible solution is to use a block with an explicit return type:

```
CGFloat (^debt)(CGFloat) = ^CGFloat (CGFloat myFloat) {
    return myFloat * 444563.4004;
};
```

to avoid that the compiler tries to "guess" the return type from the return statement.

Compare [Creating a Block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxDeclaringCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH4-SW1) in "Blocks Programming Topics":

> If you don’t explicitly declare the return value of a block
>   expression, it can be automatically inferred from the contents of the
>   block.